# SEO friendly URL delimiter for ecommerce sites for multi faceting

Tags: seo, url, url-parameters, delimiter

I am working for a project that has multi facet filters. The url that will be build when faceting applied will have several delimiters. I am not sure what characters should I use as delimiter that are SEO freindly and does not impact SEO negatively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
www.example.come/products/?facetName=facetValue&facetName=facetValue
```

More details:

The rule of thumb for "SEO friendly URLs" is to create URLs that convey their content in a meaningful and easy to understand way to a human user. An approach I like is `facetName=facetValue` (so no facetIDs or facetCodes that the user can not interpret).

Since your question is specifically about delimiters for *multifaceted pages*, you are referring to the "query part" of a URL. That means you should use the `&` character to separate the facets so it would look something like this `www.example.com/products/?facetName=facetValue&facetName=facetValue`.

[As seen here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGMCP_5.1.0/com.ibm.cics.ts.internet.doc/topics/dfhtl_uricomp.html):

> A query string. If a query string is used, it follows the path component, and provides a string of information that the resource can use for some purpose (for example, as parameters for a search or as data to be processed).
>   The query string is usually a string of name and value pairs; for example, term=bluebird.
>   Name and value pairs are separated from each other by an ampersand (&); for example, term=bluebird&source=browser-search.

Lastly, in case your facet value is more than on word use `-` between them.

You can read a great deal of things about URL formatting here --> [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html)